# Laravel: Using DB facade returns method 'table' not found

Tags: laravel

I can't make this function work:

In Controller :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
DB::table('users')->where('email', $email)->first(),
```

It returns:

> Method 'table' not found in class \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB

Also tried this function with

```
App/User::whereEmail($email)->first();
```

But it doesn't recognize the methods for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
use DB;
```

Or just use full namespace:

```
\DB::table()
```